# Intervention image Allowed memory size of 20971520 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 10240 bytes)

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I am implementing some image manipulation using great [intervention library](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation) on Laravel 5. It works fine if image is small, like under 700KB with size lower than 800px wide.

But its not able to handle large size images, I want to upload images as big as 8 MB with 2000px wide.

I have tried classic way of bumping the `memory_limit` but its not working

```
ini_set("memory_limit","20M");
```

Is there any solution which can work without killing the server.

Here is the code of my Upload service. It takes image from `Request::file('file')` and Resize it to 3 sizes using intervention.

- Big size which is max width of 2000 px, then a
- Medium 800px wide
- Thumb is 200px wide

  ```
  public function photo($file)
  {
      $me = Auth::user();
      //user folder for upload
      $userFolder = $me->media_folder;

      //Check the folder exist, if not create one
      if($this->setupUsrFolder($userFolder)) {
          //Unique filename for image
          $filename = $this->getUniqueFilename($userFolder);

          //Bump the memory to perform the image manipulation
          ini_set("memory_limit","20M");

          //Generate thumb, medium, and max_width image
          $img = Image::make($file);
          //big_img
          $big = $img->resize(config('go.img.max_width'), null, function ($constraint) {
              $constraint->aspectRatio();
              $constraint->upsize();
          });
          //Big Image
          $big->save($this->getPhotoPath($filename, $userFolder, 'b_'));

          //Medium image
          $med = $big->resize(config('go.img.med_width'), null, function ($constraint) {
              $constraint->aspectRatio();
              $constraint->upsize();
          });
          $med->save($this->getPhotoPath($filename, $userFolder, 'm_'));

          //Thumbnail
          $thumb = $med->resize(config('go.img.thumb_width'), null, function ($constraint) {
              $constraint->aspectRatio();
              $constraint->upsize();
          });
          $thumb->save($this->getPhotoPath($filename, $userFolder, 't_'));

          return $filename;
      }

      return null;
  }
  ```

Please help me how I can make it more efficient on and fast

Comment: Please try the following, use `$img` for `$med` and `$thumb` as you did with `$big`. After each `->save()`, use `->destroy()`. And `ini_set("memory_limit","20M");` is very low by the way.

Comment: 20971520 bytes is 20M, so how can you be sure setting the memory limit isn't working?

Comment: Thanks @user2094178 let me try `->destroy()` and memory will be 48M, @Devon ya its setting the memory to 20MB but its not working, giving same error.

Comment: @Saqueib...so increase it higher than 20M, default is 128M.

Comment: Thanks @Devon i have set memory to 128m, but now I am getting `imagesx() 19 is not a valid Image resource` after calling `->destroy()` on saving every image

Comment: Seems like a different problem now.  So not relevant to this question any longer.

Comment: Ya, although its working without calling `->destory()`, it seem that it is destroying the image object so no other resizing is possible. Thank again for help.

Comment: @user2094178 please help me with this, I think its good idea to release the memory after saving, but its giving error `imagesx() 19 is not a valid Image resource`

Comment: Ok, `->destroy()` also gives me `imagesx() 19` error. Try using `$img` for all instances, get rid of `$big =, $med = and $thumb =`. That should work, if not, do `Image::make` and `->destroy()` for each instance, this worked for me without  `imagesx() 19` error.

Comment: So you want me to do `Image::make($file)->resize(2000, null)->save('big.jpg')->resize(800, null)->save('med.jpg')->resize(200, null)->save('thumb.jpg')->destroy()`; or call individually like `Image::make($file)->resize(2000, null)->save('big.jpg')->destroy() ... and others`

Comment: If possible make an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 11):

FWIW, the commented solutions *didn't work for me*. That is, I couldn't get the following to work for me:

```
Image::make($file)->resize(2000, null)->save('big.jpg')->destroy();
Image::make($file)->resize(800, null)->save('med.jpg')->destroy();
Image::make($file)->resize(200, null)->save('thumb.jpg')->destroy();
```

It was still throwing the following error:

> ```
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16384 bytes) in  
> C:\Users\XXX\app\vendor\intervention\image\src\Intervention\Image\Gd\Decoder.php on line 136
> ```

---

[This solution](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/interventionimage-memory-limit/replies/153707) worked for me was to change the memory limit as follows:

```
public function resize() {
    ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
    // Do your Intervention/image operations...
}

// or...

ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
Image::make($file)->resize(2000, null)->save('big.jpg');
Image::make($file)->resize(800, null)->save('med.jpg');
Image::make($file)->resize(200, null)->save('thumb.jpg');
```

This successfully solved the problem.
The reason being:

> Resizing images is a very memory consuming task. You can't assume that a 1MB image takes 1MB of memory. Resizing a 3000 x 2000 pixel image to 300 x 200 may take up to 32MB memory for example. Even if the image is under 1MB filesize.
>   <sub>@olivervogel. 2018. Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted. [ONLINE] Available at: https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/567#issuecomment-224230343. [Accessed 14 June 2018].</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Just update php.ini file memory_limit to 256M.

```
memory_limit=256M
```

I have tried with other memory_limit with 128 and 20. That doesn't work for me. But when I update my memory limit to 256M then the issue solved for me.

In the cpanel, you will find PHP options. From that you need to update the memory limit to:

```
memory_limit=256M
or
memory_limit=192M
or
memory_limit=368M
or
memory_limit=512M
```